# port forwarding and NAT

Tags: forwarding

I've 2 locations, no. 1 in GBR and no. 2 in NO. 
I need to connect to a service in SE, from location no. 1, through location no. 2 to a service provider which only allow traffic from no. 2.

Right now we connect to mstsc to location no. 2 each time we need to connect and we would like to skip the mstsc and connect using portforwarding with trafic hidden behind location no. 2' public ip. it's not http / https but console trafic port 6040. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Setup VPN server in location no. 2 and connect to your service thru this conenction. You can use OpenVPN for this, it is not so hard to build and works great.

Comment: If I can choose, only to run specific trafic through the vpn connection it could work. thanks